# Calling a function within PowerShell ISE

Tags: function, powershell, call

Could someone tell me why I can not call a function within a PowerShell script? See below my code:

```
Write-Host "Before calling Function."

testFunction

function testFunction()
{ 
    Write-Host "Function has been called"
}
```

When I run the above code I get the following error message:

```
testFunction : The term 'testFunction' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\andrew.short\Documents\Powershell\Backups\functionTest.ps1:3 char:1
+ testFunction
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (testFunction:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I'm sure that it must be possible to call functions within the same PowerShell script. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Oh actually I think I may have just discovered what the issue is. I think the function has to exist before the piece of code calling it.

Comment: Yes....this should works: `Write-Host "Before calling Function."

function testFunction
{ 
     Write-Host "Function has been called"
}

testFunction`

Comment: @Ed209 Exactly.

Answer (score 61):

You have to declare the function *before* using it.

```
Write-Host "Before calling Function."

function testFunction {
    Write-Host "Function has been called"
}

testFunction
```